# Intersecting circles using CSS

Tags: css, css-shapes

I am trying to create this using CSS. In actuality, this is the center point of three intersecting circles. I think it is possible but can't seem to get it figured out. But then again, CSS is not my strongest item. Help?

[image]

I have managed to create a semi-circle using the below snippet (and can create the other two also) but I don't know how to position or align them in-order to get the output as in image.

```css
.test{
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-color: black black transparent transparent;
}
```

```html
<div class='test'></div>
```

Comment: Nothing I have tried has even come close. I am not sure where to even start.

Answer (score 8):

One posible solution, using a semicircle, cloned thru pseudo elements, and rotating them

```css
#test {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  border: solid 10px red;
  border-radius: 9999px 9999px 0px 0px;
  border-bottom-style: none;
  margin: 100px;
  position: relative;
}


#test:before, #test:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: -10px;
  left: -10px;
  border: inherit;
  border-radius: inherit;
}

#test:before {
  transform: rotate(120deg);
  transform-origin: 50% 43%;
}

#test:after {
  transform: rotate(-120deg);
  transform-origin: 50% 43%;
}
```

```html
<div id="test"></div>
```

Another solution, closer to the request, but using several divs

```css
#test {
  margin: 400px 200px;
}

.leaf {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border: solid 2px red;
  border-radius: 9999px 0px 9999px 0px;
  background-color: lightgreen;
  position: absolute;
  transform-origin: top right;
}

.leaf:nth-child(1) {
  transform: skewX(-31deg);
}

.leaf:nth-child(2) {
  transform: rotate(120deg) skewX(-31deg);
}

.leaf:nth-child(3) {
  transform: rotate(-120deg) skewX(-31deg);
}
```

```html
<div id="test">
    <div class="leaf"></div>
    <div class="leaf"></div>
    <div class="leaf"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Although I prefer SVG for this shape, I must say you got a nice output in your second snippet. +1

Comment: @Harry I don't have time right now, but I will !!   :-)

Answer (score 6):

Here is a **SVG** based answer. I am adding this option even though you have tagged the question with only CSS tag because SVG has a lot of advantages when it comes to shapes like these.

- SVG offers more control over the curves and are easier to create/maintain. It doesn't involve  any transforms or complex transformation logic.
- SVG is by default responsive and hence can easily be scaled without any problems.
- While using SVG, the portions of the three circles that are joined together can remain as just arcs instead of semi circles. Arcs tend to produce more gracious/aesthetically pleasing output for this particular shape.

```css
svg {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
}
path {
  stroke: black;
  fill: transparent;
}

/* just for demo */

svg {
  transition: all 1s ease;
}
svg:hover {
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
}
```

```html
<svg viewBox='0 0 100 100'>
  <path d='M5,78.77 A40,40 0 0,0 40.35,17.10 A40,40 0 0,0 74,78.77 A40,40 0 0,0 5,78.77z' />
</svg>
```

**SVG Path:**

All that is need to create the shape is a single `path` element with a few path commands which create the arcs. The SVG path commands that are used in this snippet (and even the rest) are pretty easy to understand. Below is a small explanation for your benefit.

- `M` - This command moves the imaginary drawing pen to a point specified by the coordinates.
- `A` - This command is used to draw an arc (or a semi-circle or even a circle) from a starting point to an ending point based on a given radius. The starting point is the point where the pen is before the `A` command is given. The first two values that follow the `A` command are the radii of the arc in X and Y axis. The last two values that are provided with `A` command are the ending points of the arc.

You can find more detailed information about the SVG Path Commands in [this MDN page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/SVG/Tutorial/Paths).

---

**Using CSS:**

As mentioned earlier, I wouldn't recommend CSS for this shape as creating it exactly as in the image involves lot of transformations, approximations/calculations in terms of how wide each arc should be etc. But if you still wish to proceed using CSS then have a look at the below snippet.

```css
.wrapper {
  position: relative;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
}
.arc {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 29%;
  overflow: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}
.arc:after {
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  height: 100%;
  width: 300%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 2px solid;
}
.arc:nth-child(3) {
  top: -1px;
  transform: translateX(-100%) rotate(90deg);
  transform-origin: bottom right;
}
.arc:nth-child(2) {
  left: calc(100% - 5px);
  transform: translateX(-100%) rotate(-30deg);
  transform-origin: bottom right;
}
.arc:nth-child(1):after {
  right: 0;
}
.arc:nth-child(1) {
  transform: rotate(30deg);
  transform-origin: bottom left;
}

/* just for demo */

.wrapper {
  transition: all 1s ease;
}
.wrapper:hover {
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/prefixfree/1.0.7/prefixfree.min.js"></script>
<div class='wrapper'>
  <div class='arc'></div>
  <div class='arc'></div>
  <div class='arc'></div>
</div>
```

We have to use more than one element because we need to create arcs (instead of semi-circles) in order for the shape to be exactly as in image. One way to create arcs in CSS is by putting the circle inside another `div` which has smaller width than the circle itself and then using `overflow: hidden`. In the snippet, we use three `.arc` elements to create the arcs, position them absolutely with respect to the parent `.wrapper` element and then use CSS transforms to rotate and/or translate them.

We can visually see how the SVG output is much more aesthetically pleasing compared to the CSS output. We can also see how SVG output is responsive (hover the shape in either snippet) whereas the CSS output still needs some adjustments to the positioning even though entire shape is created mostly using percentage values.

Comment: SVG is definetly a better option for this shape

Comment: Although svg is more flexible, i think vals' CSS answer is pretty good for this shape.

Comment: @Tim: vals' answer (the updated one) is definitely good but SVG is not just flexible, it is much simpler to create too. It doesn't need skew angle calculations (31 is not a round number, you'd agree) and we don't know if the shape needs to be responsive or not. If it needs to be responsive, you'd find more advantage in using SVG because the CSS one would need margins also to be adjusted depending on size.

Comment: @Harry Definitely! if i were to choose, i'll probably choose svg (for reasons that u mentioned ), but one more thing. Although even in SVG ( ie, coord geometry), we generally won't have round nos.! But the difference is that we can calculate precisely the points in SVG, whereas in CSS its mostly trial and errr.

Comment: I just noticed that his first answer was different from the question!

Comment: Yeah @Tim and vals himself had once mentioned he loves being challenged by my *almost impossible to do* statements. So, all good :)